# Does swift type inference not work with function return types?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, types, type-inference

Does swift type inference not work with function return types?

```
protocol Vehicle {
    func numberOfWheels() -> Int
}

struct Car: Vehicle {
    func numberOfWheels() -> Int {
        return 4
    }
}

struct Bike: Vehicle {
    func numberOfWheels() -> Int {
        return 2
    }
}

struct Truck: Vehicle {
    func numberOfWheels() -> Int {
        return 8
    }
}

struct VehicleFactory {
    
    static func getVehicle<T: Vehicle>(_ vehicleType: T.Type = T.self) -> T? {
        let id = identifier(for: T.self)

        switch id {
        case "Car":
            return Car() as? T
        case "Bike":
            return Bike() as? T
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    private static func identifier(for type: Any.Type) -> String {
        String(describing: type)
    }
}

let v: Bike = VehicleFactory.getVehicle() // ERROR HERE: Cannot convert value of type 'T?' to specified type 'Bike'
print(v.numberOfWheels())
```

I am trying this in playground. Why is there an error in above line?
Shouldnt the compiler infer the type to be `Bike` from the `let v: Bike` declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `getVehicle` returns an optional, you have to declare

```
let v: Bike? = VehicleFactory.getVehicle()
```

Further you have to unwrap `v` in the `print` line

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question. Vadian has already answered but a few notes on your implementation:

`(_ vehicleType: T.Type = T.self)` is pointless. You can just omit it.

Second I would simply add init() to your protocol requirements, get rid of the identifier method, change number of wheels to a computed property:

```
protocol Vehicle {
    init()
    var numberOfWheels: Int { get }
}

struct Car: Vehicle {
    let numberOfWheels = 4
}

struct Bike: Vehicle {
    let numberOfWheels = 2
}

struct Truck: Vehicle {
    let numberOfWheels = 8
}

struct VehicleFactory {
    static func getVehicle<T: Vehicle>() -> T { .init() }
}

let v: Bike = VehicleFactory.getVehicle()
print(v.numberOfWheels)  // "2\n"
```

Comment: Right. Computed property makes more sense. :)

Comment: Btw, what is this syntax - { .init() } - Is it type inference again? The compiler figures out to call init on the respective type?

Comment: You can write T(), T.init() or simply .init(). The type is inferred because you are explicitly setting the resulting type.